# Updating multiple progress bars in a datagridview using timers

Tags: c#, datagridview

The following code is part of a program that's supposed to process transactions (stored in an MS-SQL db, of course) after a certain amount of time has passed between the current time and the transaction's creation. For visual effect, I have a progress bar tracking the elapsed time of each transaction. However, even though I have different creation times for each, which should theoretically yield staggered progress bars, but they end up synchronizing instead. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Shelbyville
{
public partial class Registry : Form
{
    System.Timers.Timer tTimer;
    SqlConnection conn;

    public Registry()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Registry_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        #region
        string connString = "A connection string that's not the problem";
        conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        string sql = @"
            SELECT 
                   Time                    
            FROM TestTable
            ";
        try
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn))
            using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
            {
                conn.Open();
                da.Fill(ds, "Test");
                DataTable dt = ds.Tables["Test"];
                dgvShelbyville.DataSource = dt;


                DataGridViewProgressColumn progCol = new DataGridViewProgressColumn();
                dgvShelbyville.Columns.Add(progCol);
                progCol.HeaderText = "Progress";
                progCol.Name = "Progress";

                dgvShelbyville.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
                dgvShelbyville.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            conn.Close();
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        #endregion
        tTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        tTimer.Interval = 1000;
        tTimer.Elapsed += OnTimeEvent;
        tTimer.Start();
    }

    private void OnTimeEvent(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            int columnIndex = dgvShelbyville.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
            int rowIndex = dgvShelbyville.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dgvShelbyville.Rows[rowIndex];

            for (int j = 0; j < dgvShelbyville.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                DateTime sTime = DateTime.Parse(selectedRow.Cells["Time"].Value.ToString());

                dgvShelbyville.Rows[j].Cells["Progress"].Value = Convert.ToInt32((DateTime.Now - sTime).TotalSeconds).ToString();
            }
        }));
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

#region Customer Progress Bar
    public class DataGridViewProgressColumn : DataGridViewImageColumn
    {
        public DataGridViewProgressColumn()
        {
            CellTemplate = new DataGridViewProgressCell();
        }
    }

    class DataGridViewProgressCell : DataGridViewImageCell
    {
        static Image emptyImage;
        static DataGridViewProgressCell()
        {
            emptyImage = new Bitmap(1, 1, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        }
        public DataGridViewProgressCell()
        {
            this.ValueType = typeof(int);
        }
        protected override object GetFormattedValue(object value, int rowIndex, ref DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, TypeConverter valueTypeConverter, TypeConverter formattedValueTypeConverter, DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
        {
            return emptyImage;
            //return base.GetFormattedValue(value, rowIndex, ref cellStyle, valueTypeConverter, formattedValueTypeConverter, context);
        }
        protected override void Paint(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle cellBounds, int rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates elementState, object value, object formattedValue, string errorText, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle, DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
        {
            try
            {
                int progressVal = 0;

                if (value != null)
                {
                    //progressVal = (int)value;
                    progressVal = Convert.ToInt32(value);
                }

                if (progressVal > 100)
                {
                    progressVal = 100;
                }

                float percentage = ((float)progressVal / 100.0f);
                Brush backColorBrush = new SolidBrush(cellStyle.BackColor);
                Brush foreColorBrush = new SolidBrush(cellStyle.ForeColor);
                base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, elementState, value, formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, paintParts);
                if (percentage > 0.0)
                {
                    graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(203, 235, 108)), cellBounds.X + 2, cellBounds.Y + 2, Convert.ToInt32(percentage * cellBounds.Width - 4), cellBounds.Height - 4);
                    graphics.DrawString(progressVal.ToString() + "%", cellStyle.Font, foreColorBrush, cellBounds.X + (cellBounds.Width / 2) - 5, cellBounds.Y + 2);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (this.DataGridView.CurrentRow.Index == rowIndex)
                        graphics.DrawString(progressVal.ToString() + "%", cellStyle.Font, new SolidBrush(cellStyle.SelectionForeColor), cellBounds.X + 6, cellBounds.Y + 2);
                    else
                        graphics.DrawString(progressVal.ToString() + "%", cellStyle.Font, foreColorBrush, cellBounds.X + 6, cellBounds.Y + 2);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {

            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
```